# iOS network module architecture

Tags: ios

new to iOS

My app has to communicate with a backend java server to handle login , download image data etc. I'm confused on how to implement the network module. Should there be a separate network module for each view controller ? Or should there be a central network module to handle all the calls ? I know its a vague question but I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: You should start examining the network examples in the official documentation which use NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below mentioned link,

[AFNetworking Crash Course](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course)

[AFNetworking Document/Source](http://afnetworking.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with this

```
https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability
```

thanks

Comment: I am curious, how you will use Reachability for HTTP requests?

Comment: Dear I am lets you know in details but you comments decreses me points.If your problem has been solved then please up word the answer so the other can be benifited from it.Thanks

Comment: You need to download two classes from the above github reachability.h and reachability.m and then import it.

Comment: Ok, one more time.How you will execute HTTP GET request with Reachability?

Comment: Again my point is decrease.Dear if possible please upward the answer.

Comment: For that you need to use AFNetworking libratiry.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) can easily to implement network action (like GET, POST, download, upload, etc...)

Comment: This framework has been deprecated since September 2011 and should probably not be used.

Comment: I used this in iOS7 and it's work...

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, but the developer himself recommends people to stop using it. There are plenty of alternatives: http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D

Comment: ok... thanks for recommendation